# Decoupled or headless open-source E-Commerce CMS

Tags: cordova, content-management-system, phonegap-plugins

I'm planning to make website as well as app for e-commerce using a CMS.
I required the DB to be accessed from both.
CMS for e-commerce are easily available but they're embedded with the backend DB requests.
The app development needs to be done via PhoneGap/Apache Cordova, hence require API-like interaction with DB or something more secure from the front-end.

I was looking around for some Magento/WP-Ecommerce/OpenCart like system with good community & extensions available but with API interaction with DB.

To sum it:

1. I install DB on the server.
2. Put the website front-end on the server & give it necessary DB access.
3. Make App from HTML,CSS & JS either by some online available theme or customising the website front-end as the app is going to have much more features than the website or using some CMS mobile theme version & build it using PhoneGap.

This will help in getting a better picture of decoupling.

https://pantheon.io/decoupled-cms

http://www.onehippo.com/en/resources/blogs/2015/5/cms-decoupled-architecture.html

Comment: Use softwarerecs to get answers

Comment: Ok, sorry ! Had never heard of it. Also, it seems to have a very small community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check out these links on [building an app using cordova](http://www.onehippo.org/labs) or [feeding an Angular JS app](http://www.onehippo.org/trails/content-rest-api/introduction.html) with content. Hippo's open source java cms uses RESTful APIs to support the headless use case in addition to giving A/B testing capabilities and visitor trend analytics for web channels. You might also want to check out these blogs on [headless cms](http://www.onehippo.com/en/resources/blogs/2016/2/why-headless-cms-is-wrong.html) and [content as a service](http://www.onehippo.com/en/resources/blogs/2016/1/content-as-a-service.html).